# Android Calendar calculate hours to come

Tags: java, android, calendar

This is more logic than anything. My head hurts its pretty late and if anyone knows and wants to transfer some knowledge, feel free ;)

I get the current hour by the Devices Calendar. I also receive the current marker (AM / PM).
All I simply want to do is get hours for the next 47 hours with correct marker. I dont want military time. Just standard :P So when it hits over 12, it should default to 1am/pm. But I try to solve for so many scenarios and my head just ends up hurting :P

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the correct marker after 47 hours?
it is the same as you want to get the correct marker after 23 hours ..
The marker will be the same, unless the current time is between 12:00 and 12:59, in this case the marker will be inverted